# Broken handler in views

Tags: views, entities, commerce

I'm using the 'commerce funds' module, there is some default views included, one view shows transaction related to the current user.

/user/%/funds/%/transactions

the view shows three fields from the commerce funds table

Type
Amount
Notes

Type and Amount both had broken handlers

so i've double checked the fields exist in the database

```
mysql> show columns from commerce_funds_transaction;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| transaction_id | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| account_id     | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| uid            | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| reference      | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| created        | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| amount         | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| currency_code  | varchar(32)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| type           | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| notes          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

so i then re-exposed the fields in commerce_funds/includes/views/commerce_funds.views.inc

```
 $data['commerce_funds_transaction']['amount'] = array(
      'title' => t('Amount'),
      'help' => t('The amount of the transaction.'),
  'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'commerce_funds_handler_field_amount',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
  ),
  'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric',
  ),
  'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
  ),
  'argument' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_numeric',
  ),
  );

  $data['commerce_funds_transaction']['type'] = array(
      'title' => t('Type'),
      'help' => t('The type of transaction.'),
      'field' => array(
          'handler' => 'commerce_funds_handler_field_type',
          'click sortable' => TRUE,
      ),
      'filter' => array(
          'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_null',
          ),
          'sort' => array(
              'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
          ),
          'argument' => array(
              'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_null',
          ),
      );
```

and reverted the view, now the amount field is displayed in the view but the transaction type field is still broken.

can any one point out the mistake